# Data exchange between Data Centers

Tags: rabbitmq

We have two Data Centers DC_1 and DC_2 and each data center has an application Processor_App which processes and stores data in ElasticSearch. The data has to be exchanged between the data centers, before or after the data is processed by Processor_App and stored in ES in both DC's. Can RabbitMQ be used to fetch and exchange data across DC's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can RabbitMQ be used to fetch and exchange data across DC's?

Yes. You should read about [Federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) since I think that feature might fit what you need.